# What SeleniumIDE command use to wait for value to automatically calculated?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-ide

So I have test case like this:
User input Money value, then Discount value will be calculated automatically, user save the data.

1.Money   : 1.000.000

2.Discount: 10 (Automatically calculated -> Budget/100.000)

3.Save

I want to automated a lot of data, but when I use:

Command: Type

Target : id=Money

Value  : 1.000.000

Command: Click

Target : id=Save

Value  :

My test case immediately Save the data before Discount value calculated, what command should I use to get Discount value calculated first before click Save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the waitForElementPresent command befaroe saving the calculated value.

Use for pointing to the input field not only the id in a XPath, but also that value should not be null.

//input[@id='Save' and not @value='']

(not 100% sure if this xpath is correct)

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for few seconds till your discount get calculated, SO please use below codes.

Command: pause
Target: 5000 -(From miliseconds as i can remember.)
Value:

Or use below link :
http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2012/11/pause-refresh-and-waitforpagetoload.html